# What are best fit patterns to use when developing VSX Package or Isolated Shell Package?

Tags: design-patterns, vsx

When I am developing a bunch of designers/tools, what are some of the best fit patterns that go with a VSX Package and/or VSX Isolated Shell Package?

Any samples, links would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for general design patterns, I would suggest looking into the [Presentation Model pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707885.aspx) (also known as MVP and MVVM) for writing a custom designer.

In general, all VSPackages (regardless of the kind of tool) use the [Service Locator pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707905.aspx) (i.e. IServiceProvider) for communicating with the IDE and other VSPackages.

Comment: Thanks I use both MVVM for Designer and SL pattern for any other services, just like you mentioned :)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from IoC and DI (Service Locator) where I on larger packages "replace" the IServiceProvider with Castle (Search for Castle Project) for my own services ect. and then MVP/MVC or just PresentationModel.

I Tend to use a Command Pattern for binding Menu items defined in the vsct file.

Besides that I Use whatever pattern or practice I see fit as I would in a regular .NET solution, factories, builders, observer, and so on.

I Also tend to use Aspect oriented programming for exception policies among other cross cutting concerns (see [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/))

Comment: Thanks for the PostSharp link. Do you have a sample of blog post on how you implemented Command pattern for menu items in VSCT file?

Comment: I Actually didn't, but I have tried to brew it down to the basics in this post now: http://www.dotjem.com/archive/2009/08/19/27.aspx